# Web Scraping with R in ATPWORLDTOUR

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape if the player is right handed or left handed from this page (http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/players/novak-djokovic/d643/fedex-atp-win-loss). I used the following code to scrape this info:(1603.html is the saved link)

```
y <- htmlParse('1603.html')
x <- xpathApply(y,"//div[@class='player-profile-hero-table']")
sapply(x,xmlValue)
```

The code returns me the following:

```
"Age\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n28\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(1987.05.22)\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTurned Pro\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n2003\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWeight\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t172lbs(78kg)\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tHeight\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t6'2\"(188cm)\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\tBirthplace\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\tBelgrade, Serbia\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tResidence\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMonte-Carlo, Monaco\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\tPlays\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\nRight-Handed, Two-Handed Backhand\t\t\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\tCoach\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\tBoris Becker, Marian Vajda"
```

What can I do to remove all this letter t's and r's in middle of the result?To  know if the player is right handed or left handed I think x should be defined as :    x <- xpathApply(y,"//table[@width='570']"). What should I do?

Comment: Did you notice at the bottom of the page: **No part of this site may be reproduced, stored in a retrieval system or transmitted in any way or by any means (including photocopying, recording or storing it in any medium by electronic means), without the written permission of ATP Tour, Inc.**? Does your use of the data comply with [terms and conditions](http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/terms-and-conditions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use the wonderful `readHTMLTable()` to get all the tables from the page, then select the correct table and cell for the information.

This function takes the URL and returns "R" for right-handed, "L" for left-handed. It does that by selecting the first table, second row of the third column, and then uses `substr` to grab the 16th character. You can adapt it to whatever you like.

```
scrapey <- function(URL){
 x <- readHTMLTable(URL,header=F, stringsAsFactors=F); 
substr(x[[1]][2,3],16,16)}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Derwin.